# Ubuntu 18.04 issue with xrdp and user

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, xrdp

Since morning I am facing some issue with the ubuntu xrdp. I have 3 users **server**, **admin** and **root**. **server** user is once which is configured during the installation. if is use **root** user then I am able to login but if I use other **server** its throw following error.

```
connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1
sesman connect ok
sending login info to session manager, please wait...
login successful for display 10
started connecting
connection problem, giving up
some problem
```

for **admin** user its show following error

```
Unable to determine failsafe session name. Possible causes:
xfconfd isn`t running ( D-Bus setup problem)  environment variable $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS is set incorrectly (must include */ etc") or xfce4-session is installed incorrectly.
```

My Ubuntu version is: **Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS**
It`s fresh setup and i also try to reinstall xrdp and its dependency packages but nothing works. 
The output of $echo $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS is empty.

Answer (score 0):

After digging in deep and doing lots of troubleshooting, I finally able to access RDP from other users also. I reinstall everything and then install vncserver and kill all the running process of xface from the terminal. Now it's working.